# Upgrading Codeigniter from 1.7.3 to 2.2.2 - Issue with sessions library

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, codeigniter-2

I am upgrading from Codeigniter 1.7.3 to the latest 2.2.0 and experiencing an issue with the sessions.
If I use the old core file called **system/libraries/Session.php** its working but if I use the new session.php file, my login script isn't working at all. I mean it does nothing after I try to login with account and password. So, whats the difference in the newest version and how my script should look like? Thanks for taking the time to check my question and possibly answer me!

**EDIT: I saw that these two lines cause the issue at first place:**

> ```
>     $this->session->sess_destroy();
>     $this->session->unset_userdata( array( 'logged' => false, 'users_id' => false, 'teams_id' => false, 'leader_teams_id' => false )
> ```

**complete function:**

```
function login_do()
{
    if ( $_POST['username'] && $_POST['password'] )
    {
        $user = $this->db->where( array( 'users_name' => trim( $_POST['username'] ), 'users_password' => sha1( md5( $_POST['password'] ) ) ) )->get( 'users' );
        if ( $user->num_rows == '1' )
        {
            $user = $user->row();
            $data = array( 'logged' => true, 'users_id' => $user->users_id );
            if ( $user->users_teams_id > '0' )
            {
                $leader = $this->db->where( array( 'team_leader_id' => $user->users_id, 'teams_id' => $user->users_teams_id ) )->get( 'teams' )->row();
                $data['teams_id'] = $user->users_teams_id;
                if ( $leader )
                    $data['leader_teams_id'] = $user->users_teams_id;
            }

            $this->session->sess_destroy();
            $this->session->unset_userdata( array( 'logged' => false, 'users_id' => false, 'teams_id' => false, 'leader_teams_id' => false ) );
            $this->session->set_userdata( $data );
        }
        else
            $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error', 'user_pass' );
    }
    else
        $this->session->set_flashdata( 'error', 'data' );

    redirect( 'home' );
}
```

Comment: Won't calling `sess_destroy()` mean that everything afterwards will not work?

Comment: It worked in the old sessions library but not in the new anymore. I am setting the userdata in the below code as you can see. Updated my main post with the problem lines of code that cause the issue